# What do these Copy Only Backup options mean?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am currently trying to backup an empty SQL Server 2008 R2 database that I designed for a project that is getting shelved for the time being. I was going through the back up procedure through the SQL Management Studio when I noticed there was an option to make a Copy Only Back Up. I looked it up to see what it was but I didn't fully understand the options I was getting.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx

I read the entry above as well as other entries and I keep seeing the phrase "independent of the sequence of conventional SQL Server backups."

Can anyone elaborate what this statement means or more about Copy Only Backups in general? I'm not sure if it's the backup I should do in this case? (My first reaction is no)

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but there are a few more things that can be added. As this is an addition to the main answer, I'm going to post it as a comment, not an answer. Read the following article for a few more important details about Copy-Only backups: http://sqlbak.com/blog/copy-only-backups/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Normally when you take a backup, it starts (or continues, depending on the type of backup that you took) what is called a log chain. Let's say that you need a copy of your database and, for whatever reason, you can't use your normally scheduled backups for this purpose. Let's walk through the scenario where you *don't* use a copy_only backup

1. Normal full backup
2. A bunch of differential backups
3. Another full backup (to make your copy database)
4. More differential backups
5. Delete the backup from step 3 (you know... to save space)
6. Disaster on your actual database that necessitates restore from backup

In this case, you can only restore to the last differential backup made in step 2 because the differential backups made in step 4 depend on the full backup from step 3. Now, if the backup in step 3 were a copy_only backup, you'd be fine because you're not re-establishing a log chain (which is to say that the differential backups in step 4 depend on the full backup from step 1.

Comment: This is actually not true. You can restore from any full backup to any subsequent point in time provided you have a continuous set of transaction log backups. If you perform a full backup without Copy Only set then any subsequent *differential* backups will only work with this full backup, but a differential backup is not the same as a transaction log backup. This caught me out too - see this link for a better explanation: http://sqlmag.com/blog/breaking-backup-chain-redux-or-eating-crow

Comment: That's awesome, @toryan. Thank you for correcting my misconception!

Comment: Submitted pending edit to add @toryan's correction to the answer in the hope to reduce possible confusion.

Answer (score 49):

It's a full dump of a database, where you intent to take that dump and load it into some OTHER sql server instance. e.g. It's a nice way of making a complete copy of a DB without having to take down the db, detach the db, copy the .mdf files, re-attach, etc...

Naturally, since you're not using this "backup" as an actual backup, you don't want it to interfere with your normal backup schedules, hence the copy-only functionality. It's a full backup, but will not reset the backup schedule, so your normal next incremental/snapshot backup will work as usual.

This mechanism is necessary since the built-in hotcopy/migration tools in MSSMS are basically useless and can't handle its own databases in many cases.

Comment: So for my situation it seems like this might be a good option even though the database is empty?

Comment: If you're taking the database offline anyways, then just detach the DB in MSSMS and move the .mdf file into your archives. That's by FAR the easiest way to take it offline. You'd only use the copy-only backup if you want to keep using that db AND have normal backups scheduled AND you're wanting to take that copy to load into some other server.

Comment: Don't detach. It's risky. The file may not be re-attachable if something happens during shutdown and it doesn't shut down cleanly.

Comment: will there be any need to re-index the table once such DB backedup is restored in the target database ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating an archive backup and continuing to back it up on the server is not a concern, then it doesn't matter whether you use it or not. It will be restorable as the database either way.