# Using the backup file without affecting my database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

Me and my friend has the same database but the difference is the data in the database.

The goal is to use his database that is created as a backup file with format ".bak" with another database name.

How should I enable to retrieve his database as a new database with a new name without affecting my current database?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to read about copy-only backups too, depending on the backup strategy used with the source db (especially if it's a production sysyem). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035431/what-do-these-copy-only-backup-options-mean

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using RESTORE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx Note that the first parameter is the NAME of the database you want this to be.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there a simple approach by drop and clicking instead of doing the hardcoding?

Comment: You can use the restore wizard in SSMS. Right click the Databases folder in Object Explorer. Honestly it would do you a lot of good to learn the syntax for using the restore command. ;)